# Lipschitz functions that saturate the Lipschitz inequality on the average (part 1)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis

Consider a 1-Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ satisfying the inequality
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| \le \|x-y\|_2, \;\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^n.
\end{align*}
For $n \ge 2$, can we find a 1-Lipschitz function that saturates the above inequality *on the average*?

To make the notion of "on the average" precise, let $x$ and $y$ be independent standard Gaussian vectors, i.e., $x,y \sim N(0,I_n)$. One can show that 
$$\mathbb E \big|\|x\|_2 - \|y\|_2\big| \asymp 1.$$ 
while 
$$\mathbb E\|x-y\|_2 \asymp \sqrt{n}.$$
Is there a 1-Lipschitz function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$$\mathbb E|f(x) - f(y)| \asymp \sqrt{n}?$$
Here $\asymp$ means inequalities go in both directions up to constants.

A related question is determining the order of 
$$
\sup_{f \in \text{Lip}(1)}\mathbb E|f(x) - f(y)|
$$
where $\text{Lip}(1)$ is the set of $1$-Lipschitz functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\|x\|$ as opposed to $\|x\|_2$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, yes, the $\ell_2$ norm.

Comment: All the norms are the $\ell_2$ norm. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no $1$-Lipschitz function $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$$\mathbb E|f(x) - f(y)| \asymp \sqrt{n}.$$

Indeed, for any such function, by the Gaussian concentration for Lipschitz functions (see e.g. [Theorem 2.4, page 31](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf)), 
$$P(|f(x)-Ef(x)|\ge t)\le2e^{-t^2/2}$$
for all $t\ge0$. So,
$$E|f(x)-Ef(x)|=\int_0^\infty P(|f(x)-Ef(x)|\ge t)\,dt\le\sqrt{2\pi},$$ 
and hence also $E|f(y)-Ef(x)|=E|f(y)-Ef(x)|\le\sqrt{2\pi}$, so that 
$$E|f(x)-f(y)|\le E|f(x)-Ef(x)|+E|f(y)-Ef(x)|\le2\sqrt{2\pi}=o(\sqrt n).$$

It also follows that 
$$\sup_{f\in\text{Lip}(1)}E|f(x) - f(y)|\asymp1.$$

Comment: Ah, you are right! How I did not notice that.... Now how about general sub-Gaussian distributions.  I have updated the question.

Comment: @passerby51 : If you have additional questions, please ask them in separate posts, especially when your original question has been fully answered.

Comment: OK, fair enough.