# Lipschitz function of a sub Gaussian vector

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I have been struggling with the following question.

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $K$ sub Gaussian random vector (i.e. $\|\langle u, X \rangle\|_{\psi_2} \leq K$ for all $\|u\|=1$) and let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $1$-Lipschitz function. Is it possible to show that $f(X)$ is sub Gaussian with constant independent of $n$ ?

A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622523/lipschitz-function-of-independent-sub-gaussian-random-variables) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351031/lipschitz-functions-that-saturate-the-lipschitz-inequality-on-the-average-part), in particular, it was mentioned that the previous property holds when the vector is a standard Gaussian (see for instance Theorem 8 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/)). An answer proposed to see $X$ as $\phi(Z)$ with some Lipschitz function $\phi$ and Gaussian $Z$. Another situation where this can be proved is if $X$ has density $e^{-U(x)}$ for strongly convex $U$ (Theorem 5.2.15 in the book High Dimensional Probability by Roman Vershynin). Unfortunately I cannot leverage these options.

It is important to note this is untrue when $X$ is formed of independent separately sub Gaussian coordinates (see [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334335/lipschitz-function-of-independent-subgaussian-random-variables)) but that is a different setting.

Comment: you might want to look up the topic of 'transportation inequalities'. not sure whether Vershynin covers them, but if not, the survey paper of Gozlan-Léonard is a good place to look.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I checked Thm 6.2 and Corollary 8.14 there which, combined with Bobkov-Götze theorem, provide some other possible criteria but I haven't managed to do much with them. I'm thinking the proof for Gaussian $X$ (3rd link in my post) could be adapted by finding a path $X_{\theta}$ independent of $dX_{\theta}$, perhaps by randomizing $X_{\theta}$ somehow ...